# Load a file into a "Azure Database for MySQL" instance of MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure, load-data-infile, azure-mysql-database

I'm trying to load some data into a brand new instance of "Azure Database for MySQL". I've been provided with data files and a loading script that includes `LOAD DATA INFILE` statements. This gives me an "access denied" error:

> Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'admin_tw'@'%' (using password: YES)

As per [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54259), I think I'm supposed to:

1. Use the `LOCAL` option
2. Place the data files in an Azure Storage File Share
3. Map the share to a local drive (on my machine, I assume, since there doesn't seem to be any way to run powershell on the MySQL server itself...)

Having done all this, I now get another error message:

> Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

A quick Google suggest that the issue may be [a default setting that I need to change](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91872). However, when I run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` it comes back as `ON` already.

Quickly running out of ideas. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't have permissions for this on the created root user. I'm actually dealing with the same issue now and trying to work my way into giving that root user file permissions.